# Can I take my bike on rail replacement buses in France?

Tags: france, buses, bicycles, brittany

I want to travel to roscoff by train. However, the section from morlaix to roscoff is using a bus. In the UK you can't take your bike on these buses, or any bus. Is this also true in France?

Answer (score 9):

It depends. You need to check the specific line, or announcements about the replacement service. Look up the information booklet (“*dépliant*” or “*fiche horaire*”) about the line you want to travel on. For a regional line, go to [the TER website](http://www.ter.sncf.com/bretagne/depliant/recherche). The [summer 2016 booklet](http://cdn.ter.sncf.com/medias/PDF/bretagne/SNCFBretagne_FHWeb23_ete2016v2pdf_tcm55-87155_tcm55-88437.pdf) states

> Les vélos sont acceptés à bord de certains cars équipés de rack à vélo.
>   Service gratuit, sur réservation.
>   Renseignement auprès de Contact’ter au 0 800 880 562.

The [winter 2016 booklet](http://cdn.ter.sncf.com/medias/PDF/bretagne/SNCFBreta_FHWeb23_aut2016_tcm55-57248_tcm55-61870.pdf) states

> Les vélos ne sont pas acceptés dans les autocars TER.

So on this line, in normal service, you can't take your bike on a bus. During the summer some specially-equipped buses allow bikes, but you have to check first and you must book in advance even though it's free. You have to phone. This is a rather touristic spot but many tourists would be French so it isn't guaranteed that the person answering the phone would speak English.

I found a bit more information on the [local transport website](http://www.viaoo29.fr/presentation/?rub_code=74&thm_id=94&gpl_id=&part_id=) and on some [tourist information sites](http://www.tourisme-morlaix.fr/train-velo-morlaix-bretagne.html). Booking opens 48 hours in advance and closes at 17:00 the day before departure. The phone service operates Monday to Friday 7:00 to 20:00. The 0800 number is free from French phones (“numéro vert”).

Comment: Thanks. It's only fifteen miles, probably less bother to cycle the whole way!